# Adding one month to NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

I am trying to set a start date and an end date in my app. The end date should be one month from the start date.

e.g.

```
start date = 1st January 2014
end date = 31st January 2014
```

Currently I am using the following method to add one month to the start date, but the end date becomes 1st February 2014.

```
dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:
```

Is there a way to achieve the result I am looking for so that the end date will always be one month - 1 day from the start date?

I hope this made sense.

Thank you.

Comment: what will be the expected output of 31st January 2014? is it Feb 30??or Feb 28?

Comment: I think I'd do two separate dateByAddingComponents ops, the first to add a month, the second to subtract a day.

Comment: @isoyaboy do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComp = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Input Date: %@",[NSDate date]);

[dateComp setDay:dateComp.day - 1];

[dateComp setMonth:dateComp.month + 1];

NSDate *nextMonthMinusOneday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComp];

NSLog(@"Output date %@",nextMonthMinusOneday);
```

**Output:**

```
Input Date: 2014-03-31 21:21:34 +0000
Output date 2014-04-30 05:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: I appreciate all the help. Unfortunately I am not looking for the last day of the month, I am looking for a date that is one month - 1 day from a given date.

Comment: oh.. I see. I have edited my answer. I have checked with 31st March 2014 and the result is 30th April 2014.

Comment: 31st January 2014 will give 2nd March 2014, becuase,Feb is only 28 days.  So what are you expecting? what will be the expected output of 31st January 2014? is it Feb 30??or Feb 28?

Comment: @isoyaboy Your question is not clear. Are you want to add one month or want to find last date of the month?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
- (NSDate *)lastDayOfMonthDateForDate:(NSDate *)date {
   NSDateComponents *comp = [NSDateComponents new];
   comp.day = -1;
   comp.month = 1;

   return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:date options:0];
}
```

Comment: I have just tried your method with the 31st March 2014 as the input expecting the results to be 30th April 2014, but these were my results.

Start date: 2014-03-30 23:00:00 +0000 
End date: 2014-04-28 23:00:00 +0000.

For some reason dateFromComponents changed my input to 30th March 2014, which I am not sure why, but the end date is still incorrect even for 30th March 2014

Comment: I think it should give only next month.

Comment: It doesn't change the date, it's just being logged in your time zone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSDate *)dateForNextMonthMinusSingleDay:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateComponents *dayOffsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dayOffsetComponents setMonth:1];
    [dayOffsetComponents setDay:-1];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dayOffsetComponents
                                                         toDate:date
                                                        options:0];
}


- (NSDate *)dateFromMMDDYYYYString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:string]; 
}


NSDate *date = [self dateForNextMonthMinusSingleDay:[self dateFromMMDDYYYYString:@"01/01/2014"]];
```

I have verified the above code and its working as expected.